Backlink issue with tableau software embed?
I know that iframe generally cause issues with browser history and backlink navigation, and i know the solution seem to put a key on the iframe.
The thing is i tried to do that with my tablea element and it did not work. I can see that right after the vizEvent : firstInteractive triggers it adds an entry in the history and i don't know how to circumvent that. For testing purposes the key is Math.random()
 const initViz = async () => {
      console.log('Script loaded - History length:', history.length)
      const vizElement = document.getElementById(`tableauViz-${vizNumber}`)
      window.viz = vizElement

      console.log('Before applying params - History length:', history.length)
      if (isFirstMount.current === false) {
        await applyAllParamsToViz(vizElement)
      }

      vizElement.addEventListener('firstinteractive', async () => {
        console.log('Viz interactive - History length:', history.length)
        isFirstMount.current = false
        if (mainTerritory.label !== '') {
          try {
            await vizElement.workbook.changeParameterValueAsync(
              'Sélection entité principale (code)',
              selectedTerritory.code || mainTerritory.code
            )
            await vizElement.workbook.changeParameterValueAsync(
              'Sélection entité principale (Type)',
              selectedTerritory.type || mainTerritory.type
            )
            console.log('After params update - History length:', history.length)
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
        }
      })
    }

    script.onload = initViz

    return () => {
      console.log('Cleanup - History length:', history.length)
      document.head.removeChild(script)
    }
  }, [selectedTerritory, mainTerritory, params, vizNumber, applyAllParamsToViz])

  console.log('Render - History length:', history.length)

  return (
    <div>
      <tableau-viz
        key={Math.random()}
        id={`tableauViz-${vizNumber}`}
        src={options.url[0]}
        hide-tabs={true}
        height={options.height}
        width={options.width}
        toolbar="bottom"
        device="phone"
        token={options.token}
      ></tableau-viz>
    </div>
  )

I tried to put a key, i try to hide the div until the viz was interactive, i try to not display the viz until interactive, i tried to modify the history object to no avail.
